# This reaction ... come/comes from

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

> People of all ages generally prefer to have as much freedom as
> possible in determining their behavior. When individuals feel that
> their actions are being unfairly limited, they often attempt to
> restore freedom by directly contradicting or opposing the rule of
> regulation that threatened their freedom. Both children and adults
> demonstrate behaviors that are the results of their urge to restore
> freedom. **This reaction, termed “reactance” by psychologists, come from
> an individual's desire** to reestablish freedom and control of a
> situation.

In the past, I would dismiss this outright as a typo or slip, because by subject-verb agreement it should obviously be **This reaction comes from**.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct that this should be "comes" and not "come". A reaction is a singular noun, so you requires a "s" behind the "come".